# How would you display syncing of a wearable device to a web app?

Tags: web-app, wearables

I'm working on an app that allows the user to add one of three wearable devices to automatically add data to a web app. One of the things I am wondering about is how to differentiate the association/syncing of the device account (ex: Fitbit account) with the app vs the subsequent updates of data when the app syncs with the fitbit account. Wondering if there are any examples of this sort of functionality that I could reference or learn from before beginning.

Comment: How do you plan to do this at the moment? Also, you referred to Fibit as being an example, so can you show how they do it at the moment?

Comment: I don't really have a plan yet. Wanted to see if there was anything else out there to learn from first. And just to clarify-fitbit doesn't do it themselves. I need to show my application connecting to the fitbit account and then show that connection syncing every time fitbit data is updated to the app from the account.

Answer (score 1):

I can relate this to how Windows shows/manages wi-fi connections.

How about showing it like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One solution I've seen is to show an animated icon that represents two objects with two arrows connecting them with the arrows animated to represent data moving in both directions

```
.---.     .---.
|   |-->  |   |
|   |  <--|   |
'---'     '---'

.---.     .---. 
|   |  -->|   |
|   |<--  |   |
'---'     '---'
```

Obviously you can tailor the shape of the objects (e.g. wristwatch and cloud shapes)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have a list of all the devices. The user can select the device they want to sync looking at the name. When they press on the icon you see which device is syncing

[image: Example]

A good idea could be after the device is sync you get some vibration feedback on the device. In that way you can have a confirmation you have the right device. this would be helpful if you have multiple devices on a table then you don't know the name of the device.